# ReactJS modify array of objects spesific property

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

i got array of objects that assigned in state and i want to modify a property with input field.
I tried some below :

```
 <input
         key={item.ingName}
           type="text"
           className="form-control"
           placeholder={item.ingName}
           name="ingName"
           value={item.ingName}
           onChange={(e) => {
             item.ingName = e.target.value
            setIngredients([...ingredients])}}
         />
```

and array is like :

```
    ingredients : [{ingName: "meat", quantity: "1", unit: "kilogram"},
{ingName: "pickles", quantity: "100", unit: "grams"}]
```

These one only adds first letter that i wrote in keyboard.I need to achieve that proper working input field.

Comment: The value and the name are the same thing?? You're using `ingName` for both. That seems...odd. And if you're changing it, it shouldn't be the `key`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're directly modifying the object, which isn't allowed with React's state mechanism. Instead, you need to *copy* the object, not just the array it's in:

```
onChange={(e) => {
    setIngredients(ingredients.map(ingredient => {
        if (ingredient === item) {
            // This is the one we want to update, make and update a copy
            return {...ingredient, ingName: e.currentTarget.value};
        }
        // Not the one we want to update, we can keep using it
        return ingredient;
    }));
}}
```

---

A couple of side notes:

- Notice I used `currentTarget`, not `target`. It's not important in this specific example because the element is an `input`, which by definition can't have children, so `target` and `currentTarget` will be the same thing. But it can be important in many other situations, such as with `button` or `select` elements.
- Since you're changing `ingName` based on user input, `ingName` shouldn't be the `key` of the element. The user could make the `ingName` the same as another `ingName`. Instead, give the object some unique identifier and use that.